# Blockchain nonce value varies each load

Tags: python, json, hash

I have been working on a blockchain with a basic nonce value, however each application restart, the nonce value changes and I cannot figure out why

I have tried various ways to check, such as while not loops, if hash starts with '0'*difficulty

```py
def hash_block(self):
        sha = hashlib.sha512()
        sha.update( (str(self.index) + str(self.timestamp) + str(self.data) + str(self.previous_hash)).encode("utf-8") + str(self.nonce).encode() )
        valid = False
        if(sha.hexdigest().startswith('0'*self.difficulty)):
            valid = True
        while not valid:
            self.nonce += 1
            sha.update( (str(self.index) + str(self.timestamp) + str(self.data) + str(self.previous_hash)).encode("utf-8") + str(self.nonce).encode() )
            if(sha.hexdigest().startswith('0'*self.difficulty)):
                valid = True
        return sha.hexdigest()
```

I expect the nonce to remain static before and after application restart however the value seems to change when it is loaded again, I have checked this from the JSON output file

Answer (score 0):

After taking the night off to sleep and tackling it again I found out the issue, the issue was using sha.update and not clearing the previous result!